# SQLite Select statement returns nothing - C#

Tags: c#, select, system.data.sqlite

Fairly simple problem, I have a table in a database that contains one column and fourteen rows.

When trying to return all of the rows in the database I try the following:

```
command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Value FROM Currency", connection);
```

Yet when I look at the amount of results affected (And the lack of elements in my array) I notice the following:

[image: Huh]

Apparently there's nothing in there, I've even checked with two seperate tools that confirm the data is in there. Am I executing this incorrectly? I simply want to iterate over the values returned and store them in an array.

Thanks for your time!
Edit:

Solution!

```
int i = 0;
while (dReader.Read())
{  
    _data[i] = Convert.ToSingle(dReader[0]);
    i++;     
}
```

This works fine :)

Comment: Why are you putting a select command into a transaction?

Comment: Template from existing code, not meant to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SqlDataReader.RecordsAffected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected.aspx) is not affected for select queries.

> Gets the number of rows changed,
>   inserted, or deleted by execution of
>   the Transact-SQL statement.

EDIT:

```
while ( dReader.Read() )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value " + dReader[0]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, probably should of read the documentation. Doesn't explain why no records are being returned though =/

Comment: I've made the change. Still, I can't find an explanation as to why the select statement isn't working

Comment: Did you try something like `var value =  dReader.GetDouble(0)` inside the while loop.

Comment: The ExecuteReader method is returning nothing, that's the awkward part. It's full of rows but doesn't seemt to notice them. Event tried restarting my machine.

Comment: @Jamie `dReader` is definitely not null from your screen cap but you cannot expect to see the records all at once in debug from the `dReader`. Just try looping through and getting each value.

Comment: I've checked the array and it initialised it to the value of the DataReader, 1. I don't see why a simple select statement refuses to work.

Comment: @Jamie see my edit. Just run the code and see if it prints values into the console. If it doesn't then the problem is somewhere else (connection string, perhaps ?)

Comment: Tried it, found the problem. Probably would help if I could write a loop properly. Thanks @Bala R.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be doing a

```
 while ( dReader.Read() )
{
    ....
}
```

to loop through your resultset?